# Planning to Move TFS (Team Foundation Server 2013) from existing domain to new domain

Tags: sql, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2013

I am planning to move my current TFS (Team Foundation Server 2013) environment from one domain to another domain, currently I am reading Microsoft articles on moving but i am planning to clone the existing VM’s and do rename and then move to new domain. I have blow servers which will migrate, is there any sequence do I need to follow or if there is any better option, I need to follow kindly suggest thanks.

> SQL Server: **SQL01**

> TFS application: **TFS01**

> TFS Build & TFS Release Management: **BLD01**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you just want to migrate the TFS Sever from Domain A to Domain B, copying existing vm may not be the best choice.

You can directly migrate the domain without creating a new VM.

Fist of all, there should has the **trust-relationship** between your two domains. Then follow below steps:

1.Create all the new accounts on the new domain and **DON’T ADD THEM TO TFS**

2.Use [TFSConfig identities command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd?view=tfs-2013#identities) to change the service IDs (SIDs) for the service account to the new domain.

```
TFSConfig identities /change /fromdomain:OldComputerorDomainName /todomain:NewDomainName /account:OldTFSServiceAccount /toaccount:NewTFSServiceAccount
```

Here is a doc about the detailed steps to [Move from one environment to another for Azure DevOps on-premises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-across-domains?view=tfs-2013) and [a tutorial](https://mohamedradwan.com/2014/04/05/migrating-tfs-server-or-collection-to-another-domain/).

It also points out some precautions, you can check it：

- Once a user account is present in Azure DevOps Server, it cannot be removed or have another account mapped to it. For example, if you are moving DomainA/UserA to DomainB/UserB, the Identities command would only work to migrate the user if DomainB/UserB is not already present in Azure DevOps Server.
- Because the members of the local Administrators group are automatically added to Azure DevOps Server, make sure to remove any accounts that you want migrated from that group before you change the domain or environment.

Here is a doc about [Trusts and Forests Considerations for Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms253081(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), it could help you understand the  trust-relationship between your two domains.

Comment: according to this article [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ms404869(v=vs.120)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) first i have to complete hardware move then move to new domain since i want to keep my old environment virtual machines and do all the migration on a new one after renaming migrated vms, that's why i have been asking what is the best practice for clone.

Comment: Get it. You could configure the domain with the above steps after cloning the VM. **Note**: You need to clone first and then configure the domain.  Because when TFS migrates, you need to complete the hardware migration first, and then switch the environment.  You could refer to this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=tfs-2013. Since you are cloning the VM directly, this step will be easier.

Comment: what i want is to Clone all three machines and Rename and change their ip adress and then plan to domain move commands is this ok ?

Comment: Yes, this method should be ok. I think VM cloning can simplify many hardware migration steps.A good choice in this case.